# About an error regarding spark nlp using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I am a beginner to spark-nlp and i am learning it by following examples in the [johnsnowlabs](https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/docs/en/concepts).
I am using SCALA in data bricks.

When i follow the example as follows,

```
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.base._
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotator._
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline

val documentAssembler = new DocumentAssembler().
    setInputCol("text").
    setOutputCol("document")

val regexTokenizer = new Tokenizer().
    setInputCols(Array("sentence")).
    setOutputCol("token")
val sentenceDetector = new SentenceDetector().
    setInputCols(Array("document")).
    setOutputCol("sentence")

val finisher = new Finisher()
    .setInputCols("token")
    .setIncludeMetadata(true)


finisher.withColumn("newCol", explode(arrays_zip($"finished_token", $"finished_ner")))
```

I am getting following error when i run the last line  :

```
command-786892578143744:2: error: value withColumn is not a member of com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.Finisher
finisher.withColumn("newCol", explode(arrays_zip($"finished_token", $"finished_ner")))
```

what may be the reason for this ?

When i try to do the example , by just omitting this line , i added follwoing additional lines of codes

```
val pipeline = new Pipeline().
    setStages(Array(
        documentAssembler,
        sentenceDetector,
        regexTokenizer,
        finisher
    ))

val data1 = Seq("hello, this is an example sentence").toDF("text")

pipeline.fit(data1).transform(data1).toDF("text")
```

I got another error when i run the last line :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what your code should look like, first construct the Pipeline:

```
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.base._
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotator._
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline

val documentAssembler = new DocumentAssembler().
    setInputCol("text").
    setOutputCol("document")

val regexTokenizer = new Tokenizer().
    setInputCols(Array("sentence")).
    setOutputCol("token")
val sentenceDetector = new SentenceDetector().
    setInputCols(Array("document")).
    setOutputCol("sentence")

val finisher = new Finisher()
    .setInputCols("token")
    .setIncludeMetadata(true)

val pipeline = new Pipeline().
    setStages(Array(
        documentAssembler,
        sentenceDetector,
        regexTokenizer,
        finisher
    ))
```

Create a simple DataFrame for testing:

```
val data1 = Seq("hello, this is an example sentence").toDF("text")
```

Now we fit and transform your DataFrame on this Pipeline:

```
val prediction = pipeline.fit(data1).transform(data1)
```

The variable `prediction` is a DataFrame which in that you can explode the token column. Let's have a look inside `prediction` DataFrame:

```
scala> prediction.show
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
|                text|      finished_token|finished_token_metadata|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
|hello, this is an...|[hello, ,, this, ...|   [[sentence, 0], [...|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+

scala> prediction.withColumn("newCol", explode($"finished_token")).show
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------+
|                text|      finished_token|finished_token_metadata|  newCol|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------+
|hello, this is an...|[hello, ,, this, ...|   [[sentence, 0], [...|   hello|
|hello, this is an...|[hello, ,, this, ...|   [[sentence, 0], [...|       ,|
|hello, this is an...|[hello, ,, this, ...|   [[sentence, 0], [...|    this|
|hello, this is an...|[hello, ,, this, ...|   [[sentence, 0], [...|      is|
|hello, this is an...|[hello, ,, this, ...|   [[sentence, 0], [...|      an|
|hello, this is an...|[hello, ,, this, ...|   [[sentence, 0], [...| example|
|hello, this is an...|[hello, ,, this, ...|   [[sentence, 0], [...|sentence|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------+
```

- Your first issue as Alberto mentioned, thinking that `finisher` was a DataFrame. It is an annotator until it is transformed.
- The Second issue was having .toDF() in a place you didn't need it. (after pipeline transformation)
- Your explode function being in a bad place aside, you are zipping a column that doesn't even exist in your pipeline: `ner`

Please feel free to ask any question and I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two problems,
1. First, you're trying to apply withColumn to an annotator, you should do it on the dataframe instead.
2. I think that's a problem coming from the toDF() after the transform. You need more columns, and you only provide 1. Also probably you don't need that toDF() at all.

Alberto.